# PushViewController with tabBarController not working

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I have a tabBar application. One of the tabs has a rootviewcontroller that creates a UITableView and adds it to the subview. When a user clicks a cell in the UITableView I want to push a new rootviewcontroller but I cant get it to work.

In my appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
    //Create the window
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    //Create the UIViewCOntrollers for each tab
    _viewController1 = [[[LocavoreRetroFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocavoreRetroFirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    _viewController2 = [[[LocavoreRetroSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocavoreRetroSecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[LocavoreRetroThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocavoreRetroThirdViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    _viewController4 = [[[LocavoreRetroFourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocavoreRetroFourthViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController5 = [[[LocavoreRetroFifthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocavoreRetroFifthViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];


    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController1];
    //[_viewController1 release];

     NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, _viewController2, viewController3, _viewController4, viewController5, nil];

    //Create the tab controller
    _tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [_tabBarController setViewControllers:controllers];


    //Initialize the tab controller with the views
//    _tabBarController.viewControllers = @[_viewController1, _viewController2,
//    viewController3, _viewController4, viewController5];

    //Set the window to the tabcontroller view and make it visible
    _window.rootViewController = _tabBarController;
    _tabBarController.delegate=self;
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In my subview didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   

    RecipePageController *recipePageController = [[RecipePageController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecipePageController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:recipePageController animated:YES];
    [recipePageController release];

}
```

Comment: is..this..peice..of..code..is..in..viewcontroller1?

Comment: @AlokSingh Please uses a space between words instead of two periods. Don't type like you are talking like William Shatner.

Comment: Which tab is the problem? As you have it now, only the first tab is in a navigation controller.

Comment: in..my..keyboard..space..is..not..working

Comment: viewController4 was not working, but I added it to a new navigation controller. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each tab you need to create a separate navigation controller

Comment: Consider using virtual keyboard. Or copy/pasting space to replace double dots.

Comment: I created a view controller for the _viewController4 and now it works. Thank you so much.